# Why can't I find the inverse of $y=(c_1X^{-0.569} + c_2X^{-0.5})c_3$?

Tags: calculus, inverse

I'm trying to calculate the inverse of the function.
$$y=(c_1X^{-0.569} + c_2X^{-0.5})c_3$$

where $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$ are constants.

I don't really know why I can't seem to find the inverse.

I hope some one can explain it to me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Why should you be able to find the inverse?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for your reply I will look into it.

Comment: What I wrote was a comment, not a reply.